# Suggesting filename on right click save as

Tags: http, browser, file-upload, download

I have a site that allows file uploads and saves them with a uuid filename on the server. When a user right clicks to "save as" and download the file the odd looking uuid filename is shown in the download dialog. Is there anyway possible to show the original filename (which is saved on upload)? I've seen several post like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3569691/rewrite-url-to-affect-save-as-filename) but can't seem to get it to work on FF 3.6 or Google Chrome (which I need to support)...

Any ideas?

PS: I'm working with javascript and a python back-end, if that helps...

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a `Content-Disposition` header, set to `attachment` and supply a filename.

```
content-disposition: attachment; filename=myfilename.ext
```

I'd be more specific, but you did not indicate language or platform.

Update:

In python it would be

```
response.headers['Content-disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=filename.ext'
```

Comment: I'm working in javascript with a python back-end on a linux system if that helps...

Comment: Thanks!!! I don't suppose you know of a javascript solution? I don't know where I'd put the python that you listed... Thanks again!

Comment: @danwoods - This _has_ to be backend, as it sets an HTTP response header. You can't do that in javascript.